# Rolling up remaining rows into one called "Other"

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have written a query which selects lets say `10 rows` for this example.

```
+-----------+------------+
| STORENAME | COMPLAINTS |
+-----------+------------+
| Store1    |          4 |
| Store7    |          2 |
| Store8    |          1 |
| Store9    |          1 |
| Store2    |          1 |
| Store3    |          1 |
| Store4    |          1 |
| Store5    |          0 |
| Store6    |          0 |
| Store10   |          0 |
+-----------+------------+
```

How would I go about displaying the `TOP 3` rows **BUT** Having the remaining rows `roll up` into a row called *"other"*, and it adds all of their `Complaints` together?

So like this for example:

```
+-----------+------------+
| STORENAME | COMPLAINTS |
+-----------+------------+
| Store1    |          4 |
| Store7    |          2 |
| Store8    |          1 |
| Other     |          4 |
+-----------+------------+
```

*So what has happened above, is it displays the `top3` then adds the complaints of the remaining rows into a row called other*

I have exhausted all my resources and cannot find a solution. Please let me know if this makes sense.

I have created a [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c9769/3) of the above tables that you can edit if it is possible :)

Here's hoping this is possible :)

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may work

```
select *,    row_number() over (order by complaints desc) as sno
into #temp
from
(
SELECT 
  a.StoreName
  ,COUNT(b.StoreID) AS [Complaints]
FROM Stores a
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT 
    StoreName
    ,Complaint
  ,StoreID
  FROM Complaints
  WHERE Complaint = 'yes') b on b.StoreID = a.StoreID


GROUP BY a.StoreName
) as t ORDER BY [Complaints] DESC

select storename,complaints from #temp where sno<4
union all
select 'other',sum(complaints) as complaints from #temp where sno>=4
```

Answer (score 1):

I do this with double aggregation and `row_number()`:

```
select (case when seqnum <= 3 then storename else 'Other' end) as StoreName,
       sum(numcomplaints) as numcomplaints
from (select c.storename, count(*) as numcomplaints,
             row_number() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from complaints c
      where c.complaint = 'Yes'
      group by c.storename
     ) s
group by (case when seqnum <= 3 then storename else 'Other' end) ;
```

From what I can see, you don't really need any additional information from `stores`, so this version just leaves that table out.